# Dependency Injection of different instances of an interface

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I have an interface called Animal. It has two implementations; Dog and Cat. Since I wanted to specify which implementation I want when injecting Animal in different objects I solved that in Hilt by doing the following:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent.class)
public abstract class ApplicationModule 
{

    @Named("Dog")
    @Binds
    public abstract Animal provideDog(Dog dog);

    @Named("Cat")
    @Binds
    public abstract Animal provideCat(Cat cat);
 
}
```

Dog and Cat constructors have been annotated with @Inject:

```
public class Dog implements Animal
{

    @Inject
    public Dog()
    {
                  
    }
}

public class Cat implements Animal
{

    @Inject
    public Cat()
    {
                  
    }
}
```

If another class called C needs a Dog object:

```
public class C
{
    
        @Inject
        public C(@Named("Dog")Animal dog)
        {
                      
        }
}
```

If another class called D needs a Cat object:

```
public class D
{
    
        @Inject
        public D(@Named("Cat")Animal cat)
        {
                      
        }
}
```

When I run the app, I realized that Hilt always injects the same dog instance, meaning that that dog instance is shared among different instances of class C. What do I need to do If I wanted a new instance of dog for each instance of class C?

I did not add code for fields for brevity.

Comment: Make sure you don't have scope annotations on the  `public abstract Animal provideCat(Cat cat);` method. Code above should be creating a new instance of a Cat on each instantiation.